# Can the IDREF attribute have only local ID value?

Tags: java, spring, import, xsd

I have such element

```
<xsd:element name="Car" type="carType"/>

<xsd:complexType name="carType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="basicType">
            <xsd:attribute name="motor" type="xsd:IDREF" use="required"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

When motor element in the current document, it is work fine.

```
<Car id="car1" motor="motor1"/>
<Motor id="motor1"/>
```

But when I would like to `import` motor element from another file

```
<beans:bean:import resource="motors.conf.xml"/>
```

Intellij Idea say `Invalid id reference`, and when I run program I get an exception

```
There is no ID/IDREF binding for IDREF
```

May be I'm doing something wrong? Or may be `xsd:IDREF` equals `ref local`, and so I can't use it with import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was right, `xsd:IDREF` equals ref local.

About `xsd:IDREF` [MSDN Creating Valid ID, IDREF...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258661%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

And you can see why it equals here -

```
<xsd:element name="ref">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
    Defines a reference to another bean in this factory or an external
    factory (parent or included factory).
            ]]></xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexContent>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
                    <xsd:attribute name="bean" type="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
    The name of the referenced bean.
                            ]]></xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                    **<xsd:attribute name="local" type="xsd:IDREF">**
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
    The name of the referenced bean. The value must be a bean ID and thus can 
    be checked by the XML parser. This is therefore the preferred technique 
    for referencing beans within the same bean factory XML file.
                            ]]></xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                    <xsd:attribute name="parent" type="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
    The name of the referenced bean in a parent factory.
                        ]]></xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
```

It is a description of element bean element `ref`. And as we know, we can use `<ref local>` only for elements in current XML document.